# Are Redis' .rdb files' operations "blocking"? Can I copy the .rdb in the middle of a SAVE operation, for instance?

Tags: redis, database, nosql

I run a Redis databse inhouse here and want to make a "snapshot of the snapshot".

What the hell? Yes. I want to move the .rdb file once a day into a S3's bucket. Also, it should be a scheduled operation (probably using a cronTab function).

So here comes my question in fact: will I face trouble if the cronTab job starts running in the middle of a SAVE operation (from redis to .rdb)? There is no problem of losing some data, I just want it to work without any obstruction.

Thanks!

Comment: It should be fine. `save` is running in a `fork()` process, writes the dump and when it is finished, it replaced the old backup file at once (which you're going to backup). So you will alway backup a complete backup as a snapshot. For more information read http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redis: backing up dump.rdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182012/redis-backing-up-dump-rdb)

Answer (score 1):

When Redis writes out the RDB to disk, it writes to a temporary file. When the save process is done writing it, it then renames/moves it to the "dump.rdb" file (or whatever you've changed it to if you have done so). This is an atomic action. As such you should be fine with the method you propose.

If you want more control over it you could use a tool such as https://github.com/therealbill/redis-buagent which connects as a slave and generates it's own RDB, storing it in memory then into S3 (or wherever else you want to store such as Cloud Files or a local file) or by using `redis-cli --rdb` to generate a "local" RDB file for you to copy to S3.